# Nested for loop in Python to generate a dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

I want to iterate over all items in items and over all bands in bands (in the item object). But only the outer for loop works and just for the first item. Any ideas why?

```py
from satsearch import Search
from IPython.display import JSON
import json

# configuration
url = 'https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0' # URL to Sentinel 2 AWS catalog
collection = 'sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs'

# search parameter
startDate = '2021-01-01'
endDate = '2021-02-01'
location = [ 11.756057739257812,
          57.649809962218995,
          12.10693359375,
          57.751442372568924
       ]

bbox_search = Search(
    bbox=location, 
    datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate, 
    query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
    collections=[collection],
    url=url,
    sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
    )

def get_all_files(*bands):
    bbox_search = Search(
        bbox=location, 
        datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate, 
        query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
        collections=[collection],
        url=url,
        sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
    )

    items = bbox_search.items()

    downloads = {}
    data = {}
    
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        
        data['Product ID']= item.properties["sentinel:product_id"]
        data['Preview']= item.asset("thumbnail")["href"]
        data['Date']= item.properties["datetime"]
        
        for idx, band in enumerate(bands):
            data[band] = item.asset(band)["href"]
        
        downloads[i] = data
                            
    return downloads

display(JSON(get_all_files("B01", "B02", "B03")))
```

**Result:**
The result is, that only the first (outer) for loop works and just for the first item. The inner for loop will be ignored.

[image]

**Result after update:**
[image]

**Input data:**
This are the input data: https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0/collections/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/items

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: `bands` is probably empty, where do you initialize it?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code? Also, without an example of input data, there is little we can do. Please add a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please show an example of input *in text, formatted as code* (not a screenshot) and the *exact* desired corresponding output, also *in text, formatted as code*.

Comment: Thanks for your notation. I've updated my question with full workable code and give you the URL to take a look at the input data.

Comment: Your inner loop doesn't do anything noticeable. Plus you probably don't want to reuse `i` in the inner loop. Perhaps try `for idx, band in enumerate(bands):`

Comment: Thanks quamrana, now the outer loop iterate over all items. But the inner loop still doesnt work. What do you mean with that the loop doesnt do anything noticible? Normally it should take the URLs of the bands and add them to the band_files dict.

Comment: You inner loop may run and update `band_files`, but nothing then happens to that `dict`, so nothing notices it.

Comment: Now it works and I get all data. See the update of my question. Just one more thing to do: How can I get the bands (B01, B02, B08) nested in the json output?

Comment: That's a different question. You should definitely ask a new question about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect working code:

```
from satsearch import Search
from IPython.display import JSON
import json

# configuration
url = 'https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0' # URL to Sentinel 2 AWS catalog
collection = 'sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs'

# search parameter
startDate = '2021-01-01'
endDate = '2021-02-01'
location = [ 11.756057739257812,
          57.649809962218995,
          12.10693359375,
          57.751442372568924
       ]

bbox_search = Search(
    bbox=location, 
    datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate, 
    query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
    collections=[collection],
    url=url,
    sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
    )

def get_all_files(*bands):
    bbox_search = Search(
        bbox=location, 
        datetime=startDate+"/"+endDate, 
        query={'eo:cloud_cover': {'lt': 50}},
        collections=[collection],
        url=url,
        sort={'field': 'eo:cloud_cover', 'direction': 'desc'},
    )

    items = bbox_search.items()

    downloads = {}
    
    for i, item in enumerate(items):

        data = {}
        
        data['Product ID']= item.properties["sentinel:product_id"]
        data['Preview']= item.asset("thumbnail")["href"]
        data['Date']= item.properties["datetime"]
        
        for idx, band in enumerate(bands):
            data[band] = item.asset(band)["href"]
        
        downloads[i] = data
                            
    return downloads

display(JSON(get_all_files("B01", "B02", "B03")))
```

What I've changed (thanks to the comments):

- I used `i` in both loops. Changed the inner loop this way `for idx, band in enumerate(bands):` helps.
- Adding the key, value pairs from the inner loop to the `data` dict, too.